# Can a Corda State work with several Contracts?

Tags: corda

The Corda API does not explicitly link a State and its contract, allowing me to potentially use different contracts in different transactions with the same state class.

```
transactionBuilder1
    .addOutputState(MyState(), MyStateContract::class.qualifiedName!!)

...
transactionBuilder2
    .addOutputState(MyState(), SecondContract::class.qualifiedName!!)
```

In what situation could I need that flexibility? What would be the drawbacks of specifying the contract name together with the state?

```
// A hypothetical implementation of Corda API

@CordaSerializable
interface ContractState {
    val participants: List<AbstractParty>
    val contractClassName: String
}    

....
transactionBuilder
    .addOutputState(MyState())
```

#### A Disclaimer:

*Please note that it is a **WHY** question. I am simply looking for a use case I may be missing. Everything is working for me. I do NOT need a workaround.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Corda 3.x, you can reference any contract for a given state; it was probably done keeping flexibility in mind.

Corda 4.x establishes a link between State and contract for you by allowing you to annotate states with which contract governs them. If states are inner classes of a contract class, this association is automatic. [Relevant documentation](https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#contract-state-agreement).

You can read a discussion on various attack surfaces in this regard and how they are handled [HERE](https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/26746792?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,26746792).